# How do I create this with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

I want to create a DIV then create two more DIVS inside the firstone using javascript

i tried

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.id = "square";
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById("square").appendChild(div1);
document.getElementById("square").appendChild(div2);
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: What do you mean *it doesn't work*?

Comment: because You want class-es, but You create element with ID, and trying to get by ID.

Comment: classes are not ids!

Comment: Oh! Sorry that's true, I did'nt explain correctly... Look I will update it..

Comment: it doesn't work is no information at all - describe what does happen, because clearly the code is valid, and it *should* add a div containing two divs to an **existing** div with id="main" - so, the only logical conclusion is, you don't have a div with id="main" - see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zw688zzt/)

Comment: Well, that's true, but I create a div in Html code, then I use that script with window.onload function(){};

Comment: a snippet or jsfiddle demonstrating your code that "doesn't work" would help identify why it doesn't work - as I said, there's no error in your code (it is however not the most efficient code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("main")`?
You don't need to assign the first div an id, either.

```
var div0 = document.createElement("div");
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
var div2 = document.createElement("div");
div0.appendChild(div1);
div0.appendChild(div2);
document.body.appendChild(div0);
```

Comment: I would hold off `document.body.appendChild(div);` (should that be div0?) until AFTER adding div1,div2

Comment: Yes! your are right @JaromandaX first it didn´t work but then it did, when I followed your steps, thankyou!
Also thankyou **Bennett** for your helpful code!

Comment: @Calicol With pleasure! Just note that this will append that main div to the body.